# Proper Circuit Disconnect Size

Tags: electrical-panel

I am concerned by the size-selection' s installation of an "80A Service-Disconnect" on a 200A uni-pak, to feed the nearly 2,200 square feet modern house with a 5 Tons HVAC central system. Very modern and over-sized appliances including Sub-Zero like refrigerator as well as numerous recessed lights.

The residential work, Southern California, is recently completed by an electric contractor?

The property has a gas-fired tankless water heater, gas stove-Oven appliance.

Does current load calculation for capacity design assumes meeting 70%-80% of the current need, therefore leaving 30%-20% for potential future need, i.e, expansion or load changes need?

Is the 80A size sufficient? it does not look like there is room for expansion, if any is desired in the future.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Noting the service panel, and noting the three largest wires going to the main lugs at the top and neutral bar.  Do those wires have any figures or numbers on them?  I am looking for "copper", "CU", "AL" or "aluminum", and a numeric AWG size e.g. 4 AWG.

Comment: Also, why are there two meters?  Is there a second residence/occupancy there, and is that part of the 2200sf, or is that *yet another* facility?  Is the dryer electric or gas?

Comment: That's a lot of circuits for a 80 amp feed. Don't like to see the panel "full" like that, it's only a 30 space panel.   Only 1 240 v breaker, probably for the A/C.  Was this panel recently replaced or upgraded?  There are a lot of wire nutted connections on the neutrals...indicating changes.  Are those all Arc-Fault breakers? Maybe that's the reason for the spliced neutrals?   And why 2 meters (like Harper asked)? The one in the pic is labeled "main house" what is the other one labeled.  Lastly, is there a generator involved here?  Maybe panel in pic is on an xfer switch?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson my hunch is the *last* electrician was Mr Snippy, leaving a bunch of runt wires of bare necessary length for the task *then*) on both hot and neutral, obliging *this* electrician to extend every neutral for the AFCIs.

Comment: Further information and clarification; the above mentioned residential work is very, very new.  The 1st picture shows the main " uni-pak" with two disconnects, 80A and 50A;  The main house is assigned with 80A disconnect and the detached guest unit is assigned with a 50A.  The guest unit is fine with the dedicated 50A, as it' s biggest load is a small mini-split HVAC system, plus a gas fired tankless water heater and a Refrigerator. There is no additional demand on the system, i.e. no Generator.   However, the question relates with the wisdom of dedicating only 80A to the main residence!

Comment: @H1991 is the heat gas or electric? Also, can you get us photos of the panel's *directory label* (should be on the inside of the loadcenter door), or barring that, give us info on how many circuits service the kitchen, especially the kitchen countertop receptacles?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum service size in the NEC current code is 100a (Ca. may have an exception) the wire to the service can be derated 83%. I don’t know how they got away with a smaller service but all gas appliances 60amp would probably be fine, even A 48” sub zero doesn’t draw that much power especially if full I love mine. And the 5 ton ac is probably the largest load on the system at about 30 amps , the total lighting and receptacle load would be 28 amps if everything was maxed out so you still have room for garbage disposal trash compactor etc. the dryer may be electric and if everything and I mean everything is on at the same time it probably would be ok because of load diversity load calculations are covered in article 220 of the NEC if you want to look them up.

Comment: So that 28A figure is based on what?  Square footage and some calculation?

Comment: @Jphi1618 I referenced the code article NEC 220 the lighting and receptacle loads for a residence under the standard method is 3va per square foot,,  ok I left out the 2 dedicated countertop circuits for the kitchen and the dedicated laundry each at 1500 va. I did not even look at derating or using the optional method that sometimes ends up being smaller